# non standard XML-RPC C#

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

Hello Programmers,

I have to communicate with an API based on RPC calls with the following XML structure:

```
0x02<root>
   <dispatch>
      <module>MPAPI_RoomInformation</module>
      <function>getRoomData</function>
      <port>0</port>
      <cache_time>15</cache_time>
      <message_id>190</message_id>
   </dispatch>
   <payload status="OK">
      <root>
         <room>150</room>
      </root>
   </payload>
</root>0x03
```

It doesn't looks like this is following any XML-RPC specifications/standards, so my question is can a library such as http://www.xml-rpc.net/ or https://grpc.io/ be used to communicate with this API? if not do you have any suggestion?

If no libraries are available for this, my understanding is that RPC is basically HTTP requests with, in this case, the body being this custom XML, is that right?

Thanks

Comment: that certainly won't be gRPC (you mention https://grpc.io/) - gRPC is not based on xml (although I guess the marshaller is plugabble, so you could *use* xml under the covers. The mention of 0x02 / 0x03 makes me wonder if this is even http; that sounds like sentinels for a raw socket based protocol. Does it mention http anywhere? or just IP addreses?

Comment: I uploaded the API document here if you want to have a look (h t tps:/ /we.tl/t-2Zet3RdNWB) (remove the spaces) but they are not mentioning any HTTP or IP addresses not even ports (I guess I will have to run an Nmap to find out)

Comment: yeah, that's a raw socket API, not http; so you're probably looking at `NetworkStream` or `Socket`; re port; "The IP and Port which should be used for connection will be issued on project installation."

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my understanding is that RPC is basically HTTP requests with, in this case, the body being this custom XML, is that right?

RPC can be done in many different ways; it *can* be via HTTP bodies, but that isn't *necessarily* the case; in your case (looking at the specification), this is a raw socket API that uses start/end sentinels for "framing" (separating different messages), so: you need to get familiar with one of:

- the raw `Socket` API
- the `NetworkStream` API
- the "pipelines" API

The last is in many ways the simplest (because it takes care of all the buffer details, including retaining a back-buffer of incomplete data), but it isn't very well documented yet. [This 3-and-a-bit series](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) *might* help, or you might prefer to use the older APIs and deal with those details yourself.